# Python 3: How to run functions with parameter in random order?

Tags: python, function, random

I knew how to run functions which doesn't have parameter. In this case, I want to run functions which has parameter in random order ?

It showed the result but not random and there is some error: Please help me correct the my code. Thank you :)

```
import random
def hi(name):
    print('a ' + name)

def howold(old, name):
    print( name + 'is ' + old + "years old")

def howmuch(money):
    print(money + ' dollars')


functions = [hi('John'),howold('20', 'John'),howmuch('50')]
random.shuffle(functions)
for i in functions:
    i()
```

Comment: Your functions are called directly in the line `functions = [hi('John'),howold('20', 'John'),howmuch('50')]`.So they print a message and return None. Your list is then [None, None, None] and you try to call None(), which doesn't work.

Comment: @S.deMelo Good catch. For some reason I didn't catch the method was being called. It originally looked like the function was being compared to the string.

Comment: @S.deMelo Post that as an answer

Comment: @idjaw: dkasak and Fuxi did, with a solution

Comment: @S.deMelo You missed an opportunity to accumulate internet points! :P

Comment: Saying there is 'some error' provides inadequate information. If you want help quicker, post the error within the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this line executes:

```
functions = [hi('John'),howold('20', 'John'),howmuch('50')]
```

Python will call your 3 functions `hi()`, `howold()` then `howmuch()` in that order, then store their result in a list called `functions`. So all `print()` will run at that point. That's why, as you said, "it showed the result but not random". Since all your functions do not return anything, your `functions` will be equal to `[None, None, None]`.

Then the following code:

```
random.shuffle(functions)
for i in functions:
    i()
```

Will try to execute None(). That will produce an error, as you said "there is some error": this error is `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

How to fix: use for example `functools.partial()`

```
from functools import partial
functions = [partial(hi, 'John'), partial(howold, '20', 'John'), partial(howmuch, '50')]
random.shuffle(functions)
for i in functions:
    i()
```

Official doc here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Answer (score 3):

Try something like that:

```
functions = [(hi, ['John']), (howold, ['20', 'John']), (howmuch, ['50'])]

random.shuffle(functions)
for func, args in functions:
    func(*args)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `functions` list contains results of already evaluated functions, not a partially applied function with no arguments (so that you can call them with `i()`) in the loop.

You can use lambdas to produce new functions with no arguments like this:

```
functions = [lambda: hi('John'),
             lambda: howold('20', 'John'),
             lambda: howmuch('50')]
random.shuffle(functions)

for f in functions:
    f()
```

Answer (score -1):

In your loop, i is a function and not a string, therefore comparing it to a string wont work and you end up in else. Instead use `if i.__name__ == 'hi`